# Find a positive convex function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$, s.t. $f(a)\times f(b)=1$ and $\int_a^b{f'^2dt}=12$

Tags: integration, functions, convex-analysis

Find a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ which is convex on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b{f(t)dt}=0$, $\int_a^b{f'^2(t)dt}=\frac{12}{b-a}$, and $f(a)f(b)=1$?

Another similar question which states:

Find a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies that $\int_a^b{f(t)dt}=0$, $\int_a^b{f'^2(t)dt}=\frac{12}{b-a}$, and

1- increasing on $[a,b]$ and $[2f(a)-f(b)] f(b)=1$?

2- decreasing on $[a,b]$ and $[2f(b)-f(a)] f(a)=1$?

---

**Update:**
The matheod suggested by Mr. Greg works for all cases. Thanks everybody
the problem is solved.

Comment: For simplicity, we may assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$. But then?

Comment: Are you sure of the conditions? If $f>0$ and $\int_a^bf=0$ then $f=0$.

Comment: You are right. I edit my Q?

Answer (score 4):

(Since you already know that the case $[a,b]=[0,1]$ was enough, it would have been helpful to phrase the original question that way.)

My thought was to try a family of quadratic polynomials and hope that, by continuity, one of them would satisfy the required conditions. So consider the quadratic polynomial $f_c(x) = 3x^2+2cx-c-1$, where the constant term was chosen to force $\int_0^1 f_c(x)\,dx = 0$. Note that we just want the quotient $\int_0^1 f_c(x)^2\,dx \big/ f_c(0)f_c(1)$ to equal $12$, since we can multiply $f_c(x)$ by any constant without changing the ratio. By direct computation,
$$
\frac{\int_0^1 f_c(x)^2\,dx}{f_c(0)f_c(1)} = (12 + 12 c + 4 c^2)/(-(1 + c) (2 + c)),
$$
which is positive only for $-1<c<-2$. And, lo and behold, its minimum value on that interval, at $c=-\frac32$ is $12$. Therefore the appropriate multiple of $f_{-3/2}(x)$, which turns out to be $2f_{-3/2}(x) = 6x^2-6x+1$, is a function that works.

Comment: If you want a quadratic polynomial, the first condition says that if the interval is $[-1,1]$, then $f(x)=cP_2(x)=\frac c2(3x^2-1)$ which is your answer over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I appreciate your help